# Issue with prism-react-renderer highlighting in production build in Gatsby

Tags: reactjs, gatsby, prismjs, prism-react-renderer

I am facing an issue with code highlighting when using `prism-react-renderer` component in Gatsby. I have configured it as per instructions in [FormidableLabs/prism-react-renderer](https://github.com/FormidableLabs/prism-react-renderer#usage).

Everything works in development mode, but when I build a production version with the `gatsby build` command, the `pre` tag is not decorated with prism classes (`class="prism-code language-python"` is missing). My guess is that the production build does not include the right component or CSS, but I don't know where to start looking.

Also, this issue was not present when I used the same code 7-8 months back in another project. So it may be a problem introduced in the past few months because of a plugin/component update.

Attached are two screenshots - one with `gatsby develop` and another with `gatsby build`.

Commands I ran to setup and install the requisites:

```sh
> gatsby new test-mdx-prism-rendering https://github.com/gatsbyjs/gatsby-starter-hello-world
> npm install --save gatsby-plugin-mdx @mdx-js/mdx @mdx-js/react
> npm install --save mdx-utils
> npm install --save prism-react-renderer
```

Sample GitHub project is at [subhashb/test-mdx-prism-rendering](https://github.com/subhashb/test-mdx-prism-rendering)

[image: Screenshot in development mode]
[image: Screenshot in production build]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the answer as I tried to dig deeper.

The workaround is discussed here: https://github.com/ChristopherBiscardi/gatsby-mdx/issues/394

Apparently, the `wrapRootElement` defined in `gatsby-browser.js` should be made available in `gatsby-ssr.js` as well.